# why chat-get 3 API returns weird answers (responses)

Tags: flutter, chatgpt-api

I have added my chat-gpt API (trial-free mode to be able to test) and required codes to my flutter code.
But when I send very very simple question, ChatGPT returns interestingly weird answers to me? Is there anyone who know why I cannot get correct answers?

Example:

generated and sent text:
"Where is the capital of USA?"

response:

"text": "\n\nThis is what Mine is.\n\nRaphael.\n\nHe is a very fortunate guy.\n\nMichael eat a lot of apples.\n\nPeople here eat a lot of plant-based foods.\n\nThey always ride bicycles",

Well, I can understand the trial-free version may be weak a bit, but this is just "not-working", am I wrong?

Is there any free-way to run through my flutter application for just a couple of tests or should I purchase?

Comment: Sounds like the average LLM answer alright

Comment: if this is the capability of the API, as weird nonsense answers, why should I purchase the paid one???

Comment: I mean, you're basically getting scammed to buy in to hype technology. Like Stackoverflows management has been trying to shoehorn it into here. For instance when they added an "enhance question with ai" button that changed the languages of the questions. Or MDN's attempt at an "ai explain" that informed people that some css properties didn't exist.. On the same page as the property

Comment: wow! that's the best answer (comment) I have ever seen. Not only for agreeing you, also good to see it's straight. (about s.o. management, if there is a spring somewhere, everyone tries to drink some water from it, and they believe many will walk in when they put that button :) )